# Sum mongoid specified field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

```
def self.group_by(field, format = 'day')
  key_op = [['year', '$year'], ['month', '$month'], ['day', '$dayOfMonth']]
  key_op = key_op.take(1 + key_op.find_index { |key, op| format == key })
  project_date_fields = Hash[*key_op.collect { |key, op| [key, {op => "$#{field}"}] }.flatten]
  group_id_fields = Hash[*key_op.collect { |key, op| [key, "$#{key}"] }.flatten]
  pipeline = [
    {"$project" => {"name" => 1, field => 1}.merge(project_date_fields)},
    {"$group" => {"_id" => group_id_fields, "count" => {"$sum" => "$QtyUsed"}}},
    {"$sort" => {"count" => -1}}
  ]
  collection.aggregate(pipeline)<br>
end
```

when I execute that script, **count** result is 0.
How can I **sum** attributes **QtyUsed**?

Comment: Can you please post a sample document.

Comment: The document have field name(string), QtyUsed(int), and DateIssued(date), created_at(date), and updated_at(date).
the document isn't have nested document.

Answer (score 1):

you are not projecting the "QtyUsed" field

```
  pipeline = [
    {"$project" => {"name" => 1, field => 1, "QtyUsed' => 1}.merge(project_date_fields)},
    {"$group" => {"_id" => group_id_fields, "count" => {"$sum" => "$QtyUsed"}}},
    {"$sort" => {"count" => -1}}
  ]
```

Comment: can you give me example of projecting that?